# Codeigniter & Ajax - Condition statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im quiet confused with this code. Im reading this code of ajax which inserts the data automatically. but what im confused is this line `if(result=='12') then trigger ajax` what does **12** means why it should be 12 then conditioned to before ajax. Apparently im still learning ajax thanks. P.S this is working well btw im just confused with the code

here is the full code of the create function javascript / ajax

```
        $('#btnSave').click(function(){
        var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
        var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
        //validate form
        var empoyeeName = $('input[name=txtEmployeeName]');
        var address = $('textarea[name=txtAddress]');
        var result = '';
        if(empoyeeName.val()==''){
            empoyeeName.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
        }else{
            empoyeeName.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            result +='1'; //ALSO THIS NUMBER 1 WHY SHOULD IT BE 1?
        }
        if(address.val()==''){
            address.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
        }else{
            address.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            result +='2'; //ALSO THIS NUMBER 2 WHY SHOULD IT BE 2?
        }

        if(result=='12'){   //HERE IS WHAT IM CONFUSED
            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'post',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.success){
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                        if(response.type=='add'){
                            var type = 'added'
                        }else if(response.type=='update'){
                            var type ="updated"
                        }
                        $('.alert-success').html('Employee '+type+' successfully').fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                        showAllEmployee();
                    }else{
                        alert('Error');
                    }   
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not add data');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is part of a custom validation for this form. Those are call magic numbers and should be avoided.

Comment: The code you are reading construct the string `"12"` only when both inputs, `employeeName` and `address`, are not empty. So, when result is equal to `"12"` it will be safe to make the ajax call. Strange way to check for safety indeed.

Comment: @Shidersz so what do you think ? should it be avoided?

Comment: @abn why is that why should be avoided?

Comment: @Shidersz , i dont quiet understand, so it can be used any random number ? so can it be 20 instead of 12?

Comment: Yea, you can concatenate the numbers you like. But think about why you don't understand it, that is one of the reason this should be avoided. Personally I will prefer to see `if (address.val() != '' && empoyeeName.val() != '') { /* Do the ajax call */ }`

Comment: so should i just remove this block of codes `if(empoyeeName.val()==''){
            empoyeeName.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
        }else{
            empoyeeName.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            result +='1'; //ALSO THIS NUMBER 1 WHY SHOULD IT BE 1?
        }
        if(address.val()==''){
            address.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
        }else{
            address.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
            result +='2'; //ALSO THIS NUMBER 2 WHY SHOULD IT BE 2?
        }

        if(result=='12'){`

Comment: @Shidersz can u please show me an answer below and edit my code please sir, it will be appreciated please. thanks, just for me to make it clear hehe :)

Comment: No, don't remove all that code, just the variable `result`, and the code related to it and replace `if (result="12")` by `if (address.val() != '' && empoyeeName.val() != '')`

Comment: @Shidersz im getting ya, but last question, what if i have 17 inputs , so i should type 10 `(name).val() != ''`  in the if condition?

Comment: In that case you can replace `result` by a variable called `isSafeToCallAjax=true`. Then, on the pieces of codes that check for add the class `has-error` when that class is added, then set `isSafeToCallAjax=false`. Finally check that variable before doing the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have explained in my commentaries, and since you wanted an example. This is how I will proceed in order to avoid checking for `result == '12'`:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function()
{
    var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
    var data = $('#myForm').serialize();

    // Validate form
    var empoyeeName = $('input[name=txtEmployeeName]');
    var address = $('textarea[name=txtAddress]');
    var formValid = true;

    if (empoyeeName.val() == '')
    {
        empoyeeName.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
        formValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        empoyeeName.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    }

    if (address.val() == '')
    {
        address.parent().parent().addClass('has-error');
        formValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        address.parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    }

    // If form is not valid, return here.

    if (!formValid)
        return;

    // Otherwise, do the ajax call...

    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        method: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response)
        {
            if (response.success)
            {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                var type = '';

                if (response.type=='add')
                    type = 'added';
                else if (response.type=='update')
                    type ="updated";

                $('.alert-success').html('Employee ' + type + 'successfully')
                    .fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
                showAllEmployee();
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Error');
            }   
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('Could not add data');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just checking existence of values and appending string to it.

```
if(empoyeeName.val()=='')
```

This check empty name and add error if name is empty. else it concat `1` to result.

```
if(address.val()=='')
```

This check empty address and add error if address is empty. else it concat `2` to result.

So if both of them are non empty that means result will be `12` and than only you make ajax call else show error.

Comment: so it can be a random number ? like `10`  `19` etc?

Comment: @SummerWinter yes based on preference you can define it according to your wish.

Comment: how about this ? `result +='1';` what is the purpose of the increment add 1?

Comment: @SummerWinter it's not incrementing it's just appending string `1` not number `1`

Comment: hello sir is there any way or alternative way on removing the line `result +='1';` or i mean validating form without going there?